# How to assign colors to a scatter plot based on values in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, colors, scatter-plot

Using thebones1 DataFrame, make a scatter plot of spnbmd vs. age. The male and female points should have different colors or symbols.

So far I have created the dataframe bone1:

```
     idnum    age  gender    spnbmd  obs_num
0        1  11.70    male  0.018081        1
3        2  13.25    male  0.010264        1
6        3  11.40    male -0.029641        1
9        4  10.55  female  0.108043        1
12       5  12.75  female  0.096414        1
..     ...    ...     ...       ...      ...
480    380  11.60    male  0.116368        1
481    381   9.80  female  0.097902        1
482    382  11.90    male  0.028986        1
483    383  11.20    male -0.064103        1
484    384   9.80  female  0.049908        1
```

I understand how to add the scatter plot: bone1.plot.scatter(x = 'age', y = spnbmd')

I need help adding the colors

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use seaborn, using the hue argument as gender.

```py
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=bone1, x='age', y='spnbmd', hue='gender')
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use seaborn and just use dataframe plotting, then plot the two separately by creating two new dataframes for male and female rows respectively, and add a marker argument (you can choose from possible markers here: https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)

```py
male_bone1 = bone1.loc[bone1['gender'] == 'Male'] #Selects male rows
female_bone1 = bone1.loc[bone1['gender'] == 'Female'] #Selects female 
male_bone1.plot.scatter(x = 'age', y = 'spnbmd', marker = 'x')
female_bone1.plot.scatter(x = 'age', y = 'spnbmd', marker = 'o')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a parameter 'c' to your `bone1.plot.scatter()` function.

Something like
`bone1.plot.scatter(x, y, c=['green','yellow'])`

The 'c' parameter can be a single string, a sequence of color strings as shown above, or a column name or position whose values will be used to color the marker points according to a colormap.

Example-

```
ax2 = df.plot.scatter(x='length',
                      y='width',
                      c='species',
                      colormap='viridis')
```

[image]

You can find more information in their [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html)